# Allow cloudflare to gzip or apache?

Tags: apache, cloudflare, gzip

Hi I read cloudflare gzips files as well.

I have gzip enabled via htaccess

Would you recommend I turn of apache gzip and instead let cloudflare do the gzip?

Please assist Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I use compression on both cloudflare and the origin server (IIS). This should speed up the transfer between the origin server and cloudflare. I haven't done any speed comparisons though.